# Using @containedIn and includePaths

Tags: hibernate-search

Using hibernate search version v4.5.0, I am tring to use something like

```
@IndexedEmbedded(depth = 0, includePaths = {"id", "name"})
```

instead of

```
@IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1)
```

In cases where I dont need all the details of the associated class, but just one or two of the fields. The problem Im having is that the @ContainedIn on the other side of the relationship now seems to have no effect. I thought the point of "includePaths" was to allow you to index info beyond the scope of the depth specified. If so, how do I keep the primary entity index in synch when the associated entity changes?

Worse still I find that setting includePaths to seemingly unrelated entries also breaks my @containedIn logic.

e.g. "Person" object contains a set of "Card" objects.

```
public class Person {
  ...
  @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1)
  private Set<Card> cards = new HashSet<Card>(0);
  ...
}
```

"Card" objects are of type "Suit".

```
public class Card {
  ...
  private Person person;

  @Field
  private String cardName;//e.g. jack, queen, king

  @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 0, includePaths = {"id"})//????????????
  private Suit suit;//e.g. hearts, diamonds

  ...
  @ContainedIn
  public Person getPerson() {
    return this.person;
  }
}
```

With the above code, a CRUD operation to card is reflected only on the Card index itself, but NOT reflected in the Person index who owns that card. However, if I change the seemingly unrelated annotation on Suit from

```
@IndexedEmbedded(depth = 0, includePaths = {"id"})
```

to

```
@IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1, includePaths = {"id"})
```

Then both Card and Person entites are updated.

Answer (score 0):

"includePaths" does not index info beyond the given "depth", so you need to at least have "depth=1" for "includePaths" to work.

Since you use "includePaths", only the paths you specified will be indexed, which I think is what you want.

Page 66 (physical page 58) in [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.5/reference/en-US/pdf/hibernate_search_reference.pdf) document explained that in detail.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I lost track of this thread somehow. As far as I can see from the doc you refer to :-  
1. depth=0 is valid *"When using includePaths, and leaving
depth undefined, behavior is equivalent to setting depth=0: only the included paths are indexed"*
2. It does index beyond depth specified. As shown in the example 4:10, where *"parents.parents.parents.name"* is indexed which is beyond the depth.   

The real problem I have is that the @containedIn on the other side of the relationship doesnt update the index of the thing it points back to.